# Q: Python win32com: Code does not run after changing type library with makepy.py

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, typelib

I was studying win32com.client module and made a small script that downloads all pdf attachments from my Outlook inbox to C drive. Here is my code:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
ext = 'jpg'
for message in messages:
    attachments = message.attachments

    for attachment in attachments:
        if attachment.filename[-3:] == ext:
            attachment.SaveASFile("C:/PDF/" + attachment.filename)
            print(attachment.filename)
```

Then I browsed through makepy.py type libraries and imported "Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library (9.5) and my code does not work anymore. The error that I get is as follows:

```
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library._MailItem instance at 0x58180464>' object has no attribute 'attachments'
```

Is there anyway to undo the changes that was made when importing the type library? I tried uninstalling/installing pywin32 with pip3, but it does not change the situatio.

I am running Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for this attribute error is because your COM-server has shifted from late-binding (dynamic) to early binding (static).

- In Late Binding, whenever a method is called, the object is queried for the method and if it succeeds, then the call can be made.
- In Early Binding, the information of the object model is determined in advance from type information supplied by the object call. Early binding makes use of MakePy. Also, early binding is case sensitive.

There are two ways to fix this issue:

1. Use the dynamic module to force your code to work in a late-bound oriented way. Example use:

   ```
   "win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch()" instead of "win32com.client.Dispatch()"
   ```
2. Use camelcase sensitive keywords for the early bound oriented way. Example use:

   ```
   "excel.Visible()" instead of "excel.VISIBLE()" or "excel.visible()"
   ```

In your case use:

```
"message.Attachments" instead of "message.attachments"
```

Also, change:

```
"attachment.SaveAsFile" instead of "attachment.SaveASFile"
```

Comment: Changing to camelcase worked for me. From ns.createRecipient() to ns.CreateRecipient(). However, the dynamic solution did not.